# Tor Onions active on Tail , does Electrum use that proxy?

Tags: anonymity, security, relays, tails

When I open onion relay on Tails , and then open Electrum Wallet on LiveCD Tails
Does that Electrum connected with Tor proxy/network?

Hope some users would help me to explain this things

Answer (score 0):

Tails by design forces every connection to pass through the Tor network, the Tor service starts automatically as so this does not need user interaction. If you're connected to the Tor network you should see the usual green onion, otherwise this is the right place to ask (but in another question).

Please note that if tails cannot connect the Tor network, also Electrum Wallet will not be able to connect to its network.

Comment: I thought the blue onion in Electrum means connected to Tor , so if the green onion in there , it is already connect to Tor in Taills

Comment: I read some articles if blue onion meant connected to Tor , that's why I curious about this , and want to make sure

Comment: The green onion represents that Tails is connected to Tor, the blue dot in Electrum represents that Electrum is using Tor as proxy. If you run Electrum without Tor you should see a green dot. So to use Electrum properly you should specify Tor as socks proxy in Electrum.

Comment: My Electrum on Tails 3.5 is 2.7 version , that's  why I had some issues , so I was upgrade it on Tails not persistent,  got new versions and automatically  got blue dot/circle, but I must do upgrade as long as me liveCD,  LOL,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Whonix/Tails are *trying* to make every connection through Tor, but the really good way - as for me - is to use QubesOS and it's disposable VM's allocated in memory: this will make you not just a privacy-coveted user, but also it will make you 100% resistant to *any* data recovery tools: a memory disk is the real defense you need